# Illustrator Pathfinder Minus Front Not Cropping Circle Shape Precisely

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pathfinder, crop

I'm trying to cut a circle shape with a rectangle overlay and it's changing the shape of the crop somehow. This is similar to the pixel grid issues except I have the align to pixel grid off. So IDK what's going on. Here's what happening:

**1. I Add A Circle (with the same circle shape behind it in black to show the distortion)** Note: You can't see the black circle behind it because it's the exact same size.
[image]

**2. I Overlay A Rectangle**
[image]

**3. I Select The Minus Front From Pathfinder**
[image]

**4. I Zoom In And Proceed To Cry**
Note: You can now see the edge of the shape is no longer aligned with the same circular shape. It's changing the shape. You can't notice this unless you zoom in.
[image]

This issue is happening on multiple instances of illustrator with new files with align to pixel grid off. I've toggled the snapping features. I've checked the file preferences for whether I was running a print vs web. It's a print file.

Comment: Align to Pixel Grid on or off? Anything have a stroke applied?

Comment: If that black outline is a stroke on the green it might be set to draw on the inside of the object.

Comment: I'm starting to think Align Objects to Pixel Grid is a virus. I've always kept it unchecked. I even looked at it in transform, but apparently deselecting that isn't enough. I had to uncheck it again from the drop down menu. So what was happening was my existing objects were not aligned to the pixel grid but when I used pathfinder to crop them it treating the crop as a new object and aligning the crop (not the object mind you) to the pixel grid. I hate pixel grid alignment. Why is it in multiple places?!

Comment: The problem with Align to Pixel Grid is it's not *one setting in one place* and the logic to turning it off or on is complete confusing. You *have* to check the document *and* the objects... which seems like complete overkill to me. It should be an on/off switch like Outline Mode or Pixel Preview.. but it's not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

**Adobe treats Minus Front and other Pathfinder options as new objects distorting the crop's appearance to fit the pixel grid.** So while "align pixel grid" might be deselected in your transform palette, "align new objects to pixel grid" might be selected (hidden inside a drop down menu on the transform palette).

Also, **this selector can be turned on automatically when opening a file where someone had that option selected and then proceeds to alter the settings of other files that may not have had this setting originally**. There is also a pathfinder precision option that you can adjust to make the crop more precise.

Comment: How many digits of precision do you need?