# Pathfinder bug - doesn't cut the exact path

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pathfinder

I've been trying to go through a [basic tutorial](https://design.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-propeller-pinwheel-illustration-in-adobe-illustrator--cms-21465).
When I get to Step 7 (of creating the main two shapes), I need to use pathfinder to intersect between two shapes. But the intersect function's outcome is not exact (and actually other pathfinder functions.) I believe it's a bug.

This is how it looks with maximum zoom **before** the intersection: 
[image: This is how it looks with maximum zoom **before** the intersection:]
And This is how it looks with maximum zoom **after** the intersection:
[image: And This is how it looks with maximum zoom **after** the intersection:]

You can clearly see that the intersection wasn't made where the exact path of the yellow shape was, but a little bit downwards of that.

Here's two .ai files that correspond to both states for you to download: [Before](https://sta.sh/01ucmyre4nv9) and [After](https://sta.sh/01a1r1l5mcbt).

Comment: Align to Pixel grid perhaps.

Comment: I did try it already. It's turned off, so it not about that. :(

Comment: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/67295/120647

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can increase the precision of pathfinder from the hamburger menu. This will alleviate the problem a bit.

[image]

So if you set a smaller value into the setting you will get a closer match. However, please note that this will keep happening in many cases if you zoom close enough. It is a unfortunate side effect of how the rendering happens. For it not to really even begin to happen you should also add a point to the underlying shape. Which is why shape builder keeps adding those damn points. It is the correct thing to do in your case, but damn i dont always want to do what they think i am doing ;) So one can not always win.

Comment: Adding the intersecting point works perfectly! Thank you so much!!!